# If my dag fails for some reason, is it possible to re run the dag without loosing the progress?

Tags: airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

Let's assume my dag converts a large data set from CSV format to parquet. While running the dag, for some reason my dag fails, is it possible to restore the progress when I re run the dag?
It shouldn't start from scratch after I re run the dag.

Answer (score 0):

Airflow dag is a collection of tasks, organized in a way that reflects their relationships and dependencies. So if you have a dag with 3 tasks: `A -> B -> C`, when the task C fails, you can just re run it without re running A and B, But if you re run the dag, that means you re run the task A with all the downstream tasks (B and C).

If you want to restore the progress within a task, you can do that based on your job logic but this is not related to airflow, it depends only on the techno you use and the logic you want to implement. For example, for your data, if you have multiple files in the dataset, you can create a state store on cloud storage or a database, to know the processing state for each file, and if the file is already processed, you can skip the processing and pass to the next one.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Have you come across situation like this? Let's assume all the files are stored in S3, how can I set state store on it so that whenever I parse the directory, I should only take those files which are unprocessed.

Comment: You can create a new prefix for your state store, and when you finish the processing of a file `filename.csv`, you add an empty file (you can write some metadata like timestamp, processing time, ...) to the state store prefix. In this case your algorithm will be: checking if there is file exist in the state store. If yes, spiking the processing, if no, processing the csv and adding a file to the state store when you finish